# How to set MaxReceivedMessageSize for Azure Functions

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I'm working on creating an Azure Function which will take in a POSTed file and process it. I have the basics setup and I can successfully POST a small file. Whenever I POST a large file I get the following error message.

```
A ScriptHost error has occurred
Exception while executing function: Functions.HttpTriggerCSharp. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Exception binding parameter 'request'. System.ServiceModel: The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded. To increase the quota, use the MaxReceivedMessageSize property on the appropriate binding element. The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded. To increase the quota, use the MaxReceivedMessageSize property on the appropriate binding element.
Exception while executing function: Functions.HttpTriggerCSharp
Executed: 'Functions.HttpTriggerCSharp' (Failed)
  Function had errors. See Azure WebJobs SDK dashboard for details. Instance ID is '5fc0eaa2-0159-4185-93e4-57a4b2d4bb7f'
```

I haven't been able to find any Azure Functions documentation on where to set that property. Is it possible to increase the maximum message size for Azure Functions?

**Edit**

*function.json*

```
{
  "disabled": false,
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "request",
      "authLevel": "anonymous",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "methods": [ "GET", "POST" ],
      "route": "test"
    },
    {
      "name": "response",
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out"
    }
  ]
}
```

*run.csx*

```
using System.Net;

public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(HttpRequestMessage request, TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Info($"C# HTTP trigger function processed a request. RequestUri={request.RequestUri}");

    // parse query parameter
    string name = request.GetQueryNameValuePairs()
        .FirstOrDefault(q => string.Compare(q.Key, "name", true) == 0)
        .Value;

    return name == null
        ? request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body")
        : request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Hello " + test.Value);
}
```

Comment: Would you mind sharing what your function code and function.json look like? This looks like a WCF error message, which I wouldn't expect from an HttpTrigger call, so I'm curious to try to reproduce it and see if we can help.

Comment: Opened [issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/issues/1063) to track a similar error. It would help if you can share your code either here or on github

Comment: I've added the contents of my function.json and my run.csx files. They're not changed much from the boiler plate as I was just experimenting with Azure Functions when I ran into this issue.

Comment: Thanks. Can you also share how are you invoking this function?

Comment: I'm POSTing a file using a 3rd party tool.

Comment: Opened github [issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/issues/1063) to track this.

Answer (score -1):

Just an idea- would you consider to split the file content post to something like an azure blob, and then post the link to the file (can be protected by a timer based link) to have your azure function grab it from there? It is very common practice to split your large file upload from your primary post request which is not optimised for handling large file.

Comment: Maybe not a direct answer- but instead of waiting for MS to fix the problem, I believe this is probably a good enough alternative to work around the problem?

Comment: Agree that this isn't really an answer but also this is not a very good way of dealing with blobs - if you're going that route you should make the function trigger on a change on blob storage rather than being called by HTTP.

Comment: I don't think thats the case- the steps are you first trigger a direct upload to the blob, then you post an HTTP request to trigger the AzFn to process the blob, the ultimate trigger is still at the HTTP request, only difference is you are not uploading your very variable size (and could be really large) file directly to AzFn, which is not something it is very good at doing.